# First Ever Music Fans Stack Topic Challenge - Jam Bands

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

On January 24th of this year, the great Butch Trucks passed away. Butch was the drummer for, and an original member of, one of the purveyors of the Jam Band genre; The Allman Brothers Band.  So in honor of him, we're starting our first ever topic challenge. From 2017-01-26 00:00 UTC to 2017-02-01 23:00 UTC we're challenging you to all your great questions about any Jam Band, its members or its music.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Although it doesn't currently exist, please feel free to create/use the tag `jam-band` in your questions.

Comment: You won the first one, Should we try another one, more popular?

Comment: I think we need to maybe take suggestions for future topics.  Let me think about it and I'll post something shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The winner is [Johnny Bones](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/53/johnny-bones) with

1. [Are Jam Bands a product of the US, or do they exist everywhere?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/are-jam-bands-a-product-of-the-us-or-do-they-exist-everywhere) (4)

Other question was

2. [What does the lead vocalist sing in a Jam band show?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/what-does-the-lead-vocalist-sing-in-a-jam-band-show) (1)