# Music Fans Topic Challenge #2 - Dancing

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

Since the [current idea](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/music-and-dance-fans) for this stack is to add dancing in our topics, I suggest that we first start with a topic challenge that would be the second of Music Fans history (the first one was [Jam Bands](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/first-ever-music-fans-stack-topic-challenge-jam-bands)).

Of course, **since our site have not officially expand its scope to Dancing, the questions for this challenge must stay strongly related with music and the scope of this SE**. For examples, questions about dancing with no music, or questions about how to improve technical gestures are off-topic.

This challenge could give us an idea of the potentiality of this topic.

Could we start on monday the 16th ?

Comment: "Of course, since our site have not officially expand its scope to Dancing" just give dancing questions a trial period.

Answer (score 1):

The winner is **Chris Sunami** with

1. [Who invented the Moonwalk?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/who-invented-the-moonwalk) (4)

Then other questions:

2. [Where does the Y.M.C.A dance comes from?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5904/where-does-the-y-m-c-a-dance-comes-from) (3)
3. - [The Dancing Dead](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/the-dancing-dead) (2)
   - [Biggest hit dance song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/biggest-hit-dance-song) (2)
4. - [What makes a song "danceable"?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5895/what-makes-a-song-danceable) (1)
   - [Song of multiple dances](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/song-of-multiple-dances) (1)
5. [Has Jerome Benton ever been credited on an album?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/has-jerome-benton-ever-been-credited-on-an-album) (0)